# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while calling python script from NodeJS through spawn

Tags: node.js, subprocess, spawn, child-process

I have python script which prints out long list through statistical R (by PypeR). This python script is working absolutely fine.

Now I am trying to run this script from NodeJS through spawn functionality of child_process but it fails with following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyper_sample.py", line 5, in <module>
    r=R()

  File "/home/mehtam/pyper.py", line 582, in __init__
    'prog' : Popen(RCMD, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=return_err and _STDOUT or childstderr, startupinfo=info), 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__

    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child

    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

./temp.sh: line 1: 27500 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python pyper_sample.py o1dn01.tsv cpu_overall

child process exited with code : 139
```

Note: My python script is working perfectly. I already tested it manually.

Comment: What is `print(repr(RCMD))`?

Comment: NameError: name 'RCMD' is not defined

Comment: Gotcha problem... <br/>
I had not set R path with RCMD.  <br/>
r = R(RCMD="/home/mehtam/R-2.15.2/bin/R") while accessing PypeR in my python script

Comment: You should run the `print()` before `Popen(RCMD, ...)` where it is clearly defined (look at the traceback in your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My python script is working perfectly. I already tested it manually.

The output clearly shows that `OSError: No such file or directory` exception happened during `Popen()` call.

It means that the program is not found e.g.,

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen
>>> p = Popen(["ls", "-l"]) # OK
>>> total 0

>>> p = Popen(["no-such-program-in-current-path"])  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Also, passing the whole command as a string instead of a list (`shell=False` by default) is a common error:

```
>>> p = Popen("ls -l")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Make sure:

- your (child) program can be found in current `$PATH`
- use a list argument instead of a string
- test whether it works if you run it manually from a different working directory, different user, etc

Note: your `Popen()` call passes `startupinfo` that is Windows only. A string command with several arguments that would work on Windows fails with the `"No such file or directory"` error on Unix.

Comment: Sorry don't know how to do linebreaks (  <br/>, not working)
I do following:-  <br/>
1. shell=True is already set beforehand. <br/>
2. I tried to pass simple Popen(["ls","-l"], shell=True) and it breaks with following error in NodeJS:-

'events.js:72'
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)

Comment: @meetmehta: do you see `shell=True` in my answer? Why do you use it? Try: `p = Popen(["ls", "-l"])`

Comment: -> shell=True. To execute it as it is executed on terminal. I removed it.  <br/>
I execute your script with simple Popen(["ls,"-l"]). It is executing perfectly in terminal but not thorough NodeJS spawn.

Comment: @meetmehta: to debug the problem, try to isolate it: 1. try to run in nodejs `true` and `false` utilities 2. If it works then try to run a hello world Python script from nodejs 3. If it works try to run `true` `false` utilities in a Python script that is spawned by nodejs 4. if it works try to run a hello world R utility in a Python  script in the house that Jack built...